# ng2-chart fails on IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, ng2-charts

After importing `ChartsModule` from `ng2-charts`

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
 
imports: [
   ChartsModule
]
```

Application Failed on IE - With Invalid character

and link on `throw new Error('getColors - Unsupported chart type ${chartType}');`

**Notice: Application has all polyfills for IE included**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helped to me refusing `ng2-charts` and using native `chart.js` library. As `ng2-charts` uses `chart.js` underneath and `chart.js` has all needed functionality. I has the same problem with all polyfills included.

Comment: HI @Alinakuchai , is your issue resolved ? i am facing the same issue